# Ajax call - Response is always null

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

So, I am using Backbone and Spring. I want to POST data from an Input field and the problem is I can see the data in chrome debug, the data is there it is not null but when I look then in my database the field is null and also when I put a breakpoint in eclipse where the request is, it is null.

Backbone, here just watch the ajax code, but it Works fine I guess otherwise I wouldn't see the data in chrome debug.

```
saveNewName : function(e) {
    var inputValue = $('#newConfigName').val();
    var settingId = $('#selectReportChannel').val();
    var data = {
            "inputValue" : inputValue,
            "settingId" : settingId,

    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../customchannel",
        async: false,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function (data){
            $('.alertCustomChannel').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#alertID").hide();
            }, 2000);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('Failure in saving new Config Name!')
            $('.alertCustomChannel2').show();
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#alertID2").hide();
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
},
```

Here is my spring controller code, I've searched the whole google, I used other codes I used everything nothing works I always get null.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/customchannel", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public @ResponseBody    
String saveNewConfigName(@RequestBody String newConfigName,HttpServletRequest request) {
    String configName = request.getParameter("inputValue");     
    System.out.println(request.getParameter("inputValue"));

    System.out.println(request.getSession().getAttribute("inputValue"));
    customchannelservice.saveNewConfigName(configName);
    Enumeration paramaterNames = request.getParameterNames();
    while(paramaterNames.hasMoreElements() ) {
           System.out.println(paramaterNames.nextElement());
    } 
    return "{\"success\": true}";
}
```

I think HTML is not so important, as you can see my Input fields have the IDs #newConfigName etc. and the values are handed over to the variable because I debugged it in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8"` means you want to pass the parameter as `JSON`,thus in the server side,you need to parse `JSON` object.

If you want to get parameter via `request.getParameter()`,you need to remove this line.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../customchannel",
    async: false,
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",//remove this line
    dataType: "json",
    data: data,//send the data parameter directly
    success: function (data){
        $('.alertCustomChannel').show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#alertID").hide();
        }, 2000);
    },
    error: function(){
        console.log('Failure in saving new Config Name!')
        $('.alertCustomChannel2').show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $("#alertID2").hide();
        }, 2000);
    }
});
```